# This app isn't verified This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-shared-contacts

Hi I have developed an web application using google app engine, for `google shared domain contact`, Its working fine when I am running it in the localhost but when I deploy that application into google app engine it showing warning screen before user conforming for consent(as shown in the image).

[image: error message before consent]

I am using 2 scope `http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`. when I try to add a user information in the google shared contact I am getting a exception message as `www.google.com`. How can I resolve the problem? am i need to verify my application in the `oauth_app_verification`. Can any one solve this?

Thank you.,

Answer (score 31):

You need to go through the verification process before you launch your app. This new process came recently to protect user's data. You can start the verification by submitting this [form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) but before it is recommended to follow steps [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)

Comment: ok but I am getting an exception as `java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com` when ever I am trying to insert contact. is there any solution for this @Khalil M

Comment: @Prakash I can't be sure without relevant code snippet but my guess is you are using proxy so check if network allows you to connect via code

Comment: ok but when I run that application under localhost its working fine but when I deploy it I am facing this error. Thank you @Khalil M

Comment: @Prakash because you don't need extra configuration for localhost ,please check if network allows you to connect to internet via code

Comment: extra configuration in terms? sorry I didn't get u @Khalil M

Comment: @Prakash as I said it is just a guess, if you're using a proxy you have to add that into your proprties, also check if your firewall is not blocking your program

Comment: Can we test the api before the validation process finish? the validation takes about 1 week, but I want to continue development.

Comment: @KhalilM Hi, i've verified my app in google console, But still that error are getting. Is there any solution that app has been verified/published by google and still that error are comming.