# Google app script verify

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace, verify

I write an add-ons, and publish it.

But when the user open that first, it will see:

[image]

[image]

It show "This app isn't verified", how should i setting my app's configuration to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This app isn't verified This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437557/this-app-isnt-verified-this-app-hasnt-been-verified-by-google-yet-only-procee)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been addressed here in [Requesting verification](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#requesting_verification) docs:

**Requirements**

In order to submit your OAuth client for review and verification, you must:

Own a domain and have verified ownership with Google, and
Have a page describing your app's privacy policy hosted within the domain.
You do not need to publish your app from an account in this domain.
Steps

1. In the Apps Script editor, select File > Project properties > Scopes. 2. Make a note of all the scopes your script project uses.
2. Ensure that you have access to the Cloud Platform project for your Apps Script Project. If your project resides in a Team Drive, you must associate it with a new Cloud Platform project.
   Access the API Console by selecting Resources > Cloud platform project… In the dialog that opens, click the top link, which is typically something like [Script Name] - project-id-123456789012. This opens your script's Cloud Platform project.
3. If you can't find the left nav bar, click the menu icon in the top left.
4. In the nav bar, select APIs & services > Credentials.
5. On the OAuth consent screen tab, fill in your Privacy policy URL. This URL must be hosted in a domain you own.
6. On the Credentials tab, make a note of the Client ID for the Apps Script OAuth client.
7. In the upper-right corner of the API Console, select ⋮ > Project settings.
8. Make a note of the Project ID for your Cloud project.
9. File a review request of your project’s OAuth client. You'll need the client and project IDs you noted, as well as your privacy policy URL and the list of scopes your app requires.

Most verification requests receive a response within 24 to 72 hours. When verification of your OAuth client is confirmed, your app is verified.

Comment: I'm lost at the "Own a domain" requirement. This is a script in a private spreadsheet. Why do I need to own a domain in order for my script to be authorized to run?

Comment: How f'in un-intuitive! https://developers.google.com/apps-script/images/unverified-app-ui.gif

Comment: What a spaghetti process.

Comment: @F.Gran guess Google App Scripts devs love pasta hahahaha

Comment: @swooby for what it's worth today, I was in your same situation and thinking the same, and it looks like if you click on the "Advanced" link (bottom of second OP's screenshot) then click on "Proceed to ${yourAppsName} (unsafe)" things work out without having to go through the vetting process.

Comment: @swooby, thanks that worked... incredible how poor the UX is for how to verify an app like that...

Comment: @swooby annoyingly mine just says something went wrong and I click "proceed to...". Turns out it's google gatekeeping browsers, as I use Firefox. In chrome it worked without issue.

Comment: Is it possible to verify a Google Apps Script library?