# How to continue using google scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

Google sent me an email to do app verification to be able to continue using the gmail api. My app is basically a bunch of scripts running in spreadsheets that send an email notification when a change occurs.
Having to get a gsuite account and going through App verification to allow my scripts to survive seems very heavy process. 
Does anyone know if all these spreadsheet scripts will now be stripped of their ability to send emails in the new year? or if they can continue as long as you are running them only under your own account?
I have not been able to see any documentation on this to confirm one way or another.
Seeing process described for verification here: [Google app script verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806417/google-app-script-verify) scares me!

Comment: Change `GmailApp` to `MailApp` and as long as you are only sending an email, you will not have any problems.  If your code does something like read/change email settings, read emails, delete emails, or access user information, that is what triggers the warning from Google.  I guess Google wants it to be a mystery as to whether an Apps Script file that you own, can read, change, and delete your own data.  It would be unbelievably stupid if Google is going to stop people from deleting an email that they own from a script that they own, but I don't know of any clarification on that point.

Comment: I am only using MailApp.sendEmail but still got the google notification request. I do use other APIs such as Drive, Calendar, etc.. But they mostly seem to be indicating in their notification that its gmail API that has limited access restrictions unless the App goes through verification.

Comment: In the code editor, click "File", and then "Project Properties" and then click the "Scopes" tab.  Post the scopes that you are using in your original question.

Comment: Here are the scopes used: 8 OAuth Scopes required by the script:
https://mail.google.com/
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

Comment: The problem is the scope "https://mail.google.com/"  If you are truly only just sending emails, then all you need is the scope: "googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail"  You can manually set the scopes in the appsscript.json file, and not use  "https://mail.google.com/"

Comment: Thanks. I think the script.send_mail is all I need. Never set scopes manually. How do you  set that json file? Any example I can follow?

Comment: Searched and found answer in this article: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes . Much thanks for your help!!