# I am trying to run a simple Google Apps Script in Spreadsheet and getting error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Spreadsheet where I created a very simple script and when I am trying to run it then it asks permissions I authorize it then it gives me an error.

**Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified by Google in order to use Google Sign in.**

How funny and ridiculous is that. So to test 'Hello World' like script it needs to be verified by Google?

Comment: That's normal behavior. You have to authorize scripts.  Unless of course you don't trust yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437557/this-app-isnt-verified-this-app-hasnt-been-verified-by-google-yet-only-procee

Comment: @Cooper how is my question the same as you comment here? I authorize it but then it gives me an error I wrote above?
In answer you posted it says to go and verify the application. So you are saying if I want to write a simple 'Hello World' script I need to get verification?

Comment: Verification is not always required. It depends upon number of users mostly I think. If the script is only for you then I don’t think it’s required. But authorization is required.

Comment: @Cooper yes I know that and I am the only user who uses it. I authorize it then getting the above error message. I cannot test a simple google apps script and I found that it is a google bug and there is a workaround for it. But because you closed my question no one answered it and I had to research and find it myself.
Here is the link to the issue - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820

Comment: Well, i apologize for that but thanks for reporting the issue to me.

Comment: I see the problem was apparently not happening on commercial accounts so I couldn't see it.  I was under the impression that you were disturbed that you had to authorize your script the first time you ran it which is normal.  It's difficult sometiimes to see OP's point of view that's why it's always helpful to provide a code sample and an exact statement of the error message along with detail instructions on what steps are required to get the error.  You see in that issue that the examiner had great difficulty in getting the error to occur for him.

Comment: Ran out of room. That being said I should have take more time to access the situation in your case and I deeply apologize for not doing so.

Comment: @Cooper no problem