# This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-api

I try to use Gmail API with nodejs.

after copy and paste the quickstart code on [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs)

Then, I get this error ;

> [image: Open this image]

It says that `This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer.`

What I can do next ??

Comment: For testing, you can click on the link *Go to Quickstart (unsafe)*. When your app is trusted, the warning will be removed.

Comment: nice. thanks dude 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This app isn't verified This app hasn't been verified by Google yet. Only proceed if you know and trust the developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45437557/this-app-isnt-verified-this-app-hasnt-been-verified-by-google-yet-only-procee)